# What's the best way to render "not always" in Russian?

Tags: перевод

For example, in the sentence "Great people are not always wise." I know I could say something like Великие люди иногда не мудрые but is there a more elegant way to say this?

Answer (score 20):

I believe the literal translation `не всегда` better fits your needs:

> Великие люди не всегда мудры.

Comment: Здесь определенно стоит использовать краткую форму прилагательного: _„Вели́кие лю́ди не всегда́ мудры́“_.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov, you are right, thank you.

Comment: Maybe even "Великие не всегда мудры" as a shorter alternative — after all, such wording is pretty common to aphorisms.

Answer (score 4):

Is it about great people not being wise all the time, or about not every great person being wise?

If latter, I would write it as `Не все великие люди мудры`.

Comment: Your confusion over the meaning reminds of a Dilbert cartoon: http://www.dilbert.com/fast/2001-04-19/.

Answer (score 1):

You can also say

> Не каждый великий человек мудр.

Answer (score 1):

"Не обязательно" also will do in this case.

> Великие люди не обязательно мудры.

Generally speaking, you're not talking about time in this sentence, but about a logical relationship, namely an absence of cause-effect relation. So using of the time-related words like `всегда` and `иногда` isn't essential, and any way to express this simple logic is OK. For example:

> Из того, что человек велик, не следует, что он мудр.